# MySQL retrieve friends of friends structure and performance

Tags: mysql, database, performance, structure

I would simply like to find a database structure in MySQL to get all users friends of friends and the corresponding query to retrieve them. (friend links are bi-directional)

I have found a couple posts related to that, but my concern is the performance:

### **Structure 1**

Many posts suggest a structure where you have a table in which each row represents a friendship link e.g:

```
    CREATE TABLE `friends` (
    `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `friend_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    )
```

saying the user '1' has three friend '2','3','4' and user '2' has two friend '1','5' . Your friend table would look like this:

```
    user_id    |    friend_id
    1          |    2
    1          |    3
    1          |    4
    2          |    1
    2          |    5
```

**friends of friends query:** How to select friends of friends can be seen here [SQL to get friends AND friends of friends of a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806881/sql-to-get-friends-and-friends-of-friends-of-a-user). The rsult of the query for user '1' is supposed to give (1,2,3,4,5)

My concern: The average fb-user has about 140 friends. Frequent users will have a lot more.
If I have 20.000 users this will end up in at least 3million rows.

### **Structure 2**

If I could use a structure like this:

```
    CREATE TABLE `friends` (
    `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `friend_1` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `friend_2` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `friend_3` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `friend_4` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    ....
    )
```

My table would look like this (taking example from above):

```
    user_id  |  friend_1  |  friend_2  |  friend_3  |  ...
    1        |  2         |  3         |  4         |
    2        |  1         |  5         |            |...
```

Now I have only 20.000 rows.

**friends of friends query:** To select user friends of friends I tried

```
    Select * FROM friends as a
    WHERE a.user_id 
    IN (
        SELECT * FROM friends AS b
        WHERE b.user_id = '1'
    )
```

but I get an error "#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s) ". I think the problem is, that the sub-selection passes a row, not a column?

### **Questions**

I hope you understand my concern. I would be really really happy about any input to these questions

1)
**find a query that returns all friends of friends for a specified user in *structure 2*?**

2)
**Which structure allows me to return friends of friends quicker?** 
In *structure 2* I think the "join *row* with *column*" could be slow, if its even possible to use a join here. Thank you for any suggestions. If you could think of any other structures, maybe taking advantage of the small-world-network-type I'd be happy to hear them.

THANK YOU!!

Comment: Don't use `x IN (SELECT y FROM z)` in MySQL. Try rewriting it with `EXISTS`.

Comment: don't comment your own entry, edit it

Answer (score 3):

Definitely use the first structure. Queries for the second structure will be huge, hard to maintain and slow because of complicated clauses.

A fast enough query for the first approach:

```
(
    select friend_id 
    from friends 
    where user_id = 1
) union (
    select distinct ff.friend_id 
    from 
        friends f
        join friends ff on ff.user_id = f.friend_id
    where f.user_id = 1
)
```

For the best performance you need to have these indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE `friends` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `friends_idx` (`user_id` ASC, `friend_id` ASC);
ALTER TABLE `friends` ADD INDEX `friends_user_id_idx` (`user_id` ASC);
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you think of a way to bring the last "where" statement into the join? This would probably increase performance, since you would have a smaller joined table, and do not have select from a big one. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Corn999 the last `where` clause will by applied on one table only. You will not get any benefit if you move the condition to the `join` clause. All you need is to have indexes on `user_id` and on `friend_id`.

Comment: @Corn999 The slowest part of this query should be `union` because this will remove duplicates (because many friends can have similar friends).

Comment: @Corn999 I have updated the query and added indexes for the best possible performance.

Comment: Thank you a lot! With @radu answere, I also came up with this query `SELECT DISTINCT u.user_id FROM friends AS u    INNER JOIN (    SELECT g.friends_ID FROM friends AS g WHERE g.user_id = 1 ) AS f    ON (u.friend_id=f.friend_id AND u.user_ID <> 1)`  I do not know which will be quicker, but will definitly test both and post the results as answere. thank you again for your input!

Comment: When will be able to, i will +1 your great answere of course!

Comment: @Corn999 But keep in mind that your query is a little different. My query returns `friends` + `firends of friends`. Your query returns `friends of friends` + `friends which you have in common with friends of friends`, but not all friends.

Comment: @Corn999 I was a little incorrect in my last comment. Actually your query returns `friends of friends` + `friends which you have in common with other your friends`. If you use only the second part of my query then it should give you the same result as yours.

Comment: I've set up a test app just because I was curious about the performance and implementing a friend relationship as well. `Query took 0.1616 seconds.` That's for 4.889.485 records in the friends table. And now the surprise: It's only 10.000 users with each of them having ~250 friends. Now make your guess how this will work for 100.000 users. I have doubts this is going to work fast for a really huge site.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say you ought to use the first structure. It's more flexible in my opinion. My solution for the query would be a simple sub-query, like this:

```
SELECT friend_id FROM friends WHERE user_id IN (

       SELECT friend_id FROM friends WHERE user_id='$USER_ID'

);
```

EDIT: Sorry I just woke up and realized after posting a reply that this wasn't at all what you were looking for. Sry.

Comment: haha, I know that too, thank you anyways for waking up and thinking about other people problems right away :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use "Structure 2" you cannot create a column for all users if just 1 user have let's say 100 friends (what abaout 10K friends or more ?) it results in low performance, for structure 1 you can do a simple join to the same table:

```
select u.user_id, f.friend_id 
from friends as u 
  inner join friends as f
    on (u.friend_id=f.friend_id);
```

EDIT:

you're error #1241 means that you use * in the subselect and the table returns more than 1 column, your subquery should return just one colums (no mather how many rows), so change your "*" with a "user_id" (without quotes)

Solution 1 is not only faster it is flexible, I don't recomand a subquery for a simple select like this, just join the same table (it's much faster than a subselect).

Solution 2 in my opinion is not a solution at all, it's not flexible, it slower, it uses more space on HD, more columns means less performance in mysql. How can you index such a thing? And how can you select by friend_id not by user_id, you look in every column for that friend_id ?

Comment: I cannot get the th line-break to work. added   two spaces, but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand what you are saying. Can you think of a structure where you'd just insert e.g. (1,2) instead of (1,2),(2,1) as implied by you? this would cut the size of the tably by half

Comment: @Corn: add 4 spaces in every line. Or select all the code and click on the `{}` (Code Sample) button in the Edit window.

Comment: @ypercube: My problem is the ADD COMMENT box. I just dont get line-breaks working here. In documentation it says two spaces.

Comment: @Radu: If could I'd definitely give you a plus 1 but im not certified to do that yet. When I will you get one from me. See Karolis answere how I'd make the query (if interested). Thank you again, I'll post results when tested

Comment: @Corn999 Sorry I missed this part of the question "all users friends of friends" I read it as "all users friends" :)

Answer (score 0):

As the below answers state, solution 1 is preferred to solution 2. Also solution 1 will work out for a decent amount of data.

However, when things go bigger there is also a third solution - Graph Databases.

When your data model focuses on the "relations" instead of the "objects" RDBMSs don't scale well since they have to perform lookups through the tables concerned. DB Indexes make this easier but it was not enough so Graph Databases came to the rescue.

A Graph DB actually "stores" the relations next to each entity making it much faster to perform tasks like yours.

Here is some information to get you started:

http://www.slideshare.net/maxdemarzi/graph-database-use-cases

**Neo4j** or **OrientDB** are among the popular choices.